# How to reset navigation.params object data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my code

```
{
  key: "id-16263358905-23",
  params: { "3067": 1 },
  routeName: "Details"
};
```

I want to "params":{} ==>

```
{
  key: "id-16263358905-23",
  params: {},
  routeName: "Details"
};
```

Please, help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - this is not your Code this is your response from your navigation object

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {"key": "id-16263358905-23", "params": {"3067": 1}, "routeName": "Details"}

let newObj = {...obj,params:{}}
```

**you can do this, but over here the main question is from where you are getting that object, as per that we have to change the logic what i have mentioned above is simple common logic to update object value.**

Comment: I get this data from "this.props.navigation.state" . so I used this code "this.props.navigation.setParams({ })" but this is not working. I want to "param" : { } , pls help me

Comment: let obj = this.props.navigation.state

let newObj = {...obj,params:{}}

now use newObj as per your need, it will have {"key": "id-16263358905-23", "params": {}, "routeName": "Details"}

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the params data as below:

```
useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => {
    if (route.params) {
      const keys = Object.keys(route.params)
      if (keys && keys.length > 0) {
       const removeableKey = keys[0]
       delete route.params[removeableKey] // save data before deleting the params
      }         
    }
  }, [route.params]))
```